# Better way to make MPMoviePlayer with Overlay view

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

When we creating application with MPMoviePlayer (within custom UIViewController) and with overlay UIViewController on top of movie player what is better:
- Load movie in player with self.view.presentModalView... or self.view.addSubView...
Or is there any other better way. I now work with modal views and everything works except I have to implement some custom rotations. I am looking for more clear way to make this.

Ok maybe some more details. In iPhone app I add player like modal view and add overlay view to it and that works. But this is universal app and it doesn't work on iPad the same way it works on iPhone. In ipad splitView my player is on details side (nonfullscreen), when I double tap player it goes fullscreen. And now player is key window. Here is the biggest issue. I tried to add overlay view as subviw and modal view and I made it but that overlay is not aware of device orientation, and I have to transform overlay elements and this is what I am trying to avoid. Is there any way to detect rotation on that view?

Comment: This question is far to broad and argumentative. There is no better way. There are options that apply to certain situations.

Comment: I was hoping for some example on how other people add player with overlay view.

Comment: I added more information in question.

Comment: Have you understood the principals of delegation?

Comment: I learned about delegates. But I don't know how that can help me here :(

Comment: When I try to set delegate on my overlay view I got warning 'UIView may not respond to 'setDelegate''. This is how I try to add delegate to view that can rotate: '[over.view setDelegate:cp];'

Answer (score 6):

Simple and most elegant solution:

Do not use the "real" fullscreen mode but scale the MPMoviePlayerController's view towards a screen-filling size - `MPMoviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768.0f, 1024.0f);`. Keep the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `view` on top of a regular `UIViewController`'s `view` that allows rotations (addSubview). Keep your custom interface view on top of the MPMoviePlayerController's view (addSubview) and presto, you will get a properly rotating video player no matter if you run it in "fullscreen" or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution but I am not very proud because I this that there is some better way, but this workaround works:
- In project I have on singleton class that contains some global data for me.
- When application start in detail view (UISplitView) `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method is called first. Here I get current orientation and store it in singleton class.
- Later when I add overlay on top of player I read data from singleton and transform overlay elements.

Answer (score 0):

According to above I did something like this:

```
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];

mp.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

mp.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);

[self.view addSubview:mp.view];

mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[self.view addSubview:self.myOverlay];


[mp play];
```

Actually it was so easy! Just choose control style to None and add your low opacity view on the player view.